# HTML Width Percentage

Tags: html, css

```
#wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 1020px;
        width: 98%;
        background-color: #FEFBE8;
        border: 2px solid #878E63;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(12,3,25,0.8);
}
```

I am following this tutorial online and it has a div element with the id wrapper which wraps everything that is containing in the body. So:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
...
</div>
</body>
```

It is a tutorial in making a responsive website. I am a little confused on why for the css of the wrapper he includes max-width: 1020px **AND** width: 98%. So is this saying that the div element with the id wrapper will be 98% of 1020px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `max-width` -- the maximum width an element can reach
- `width` the width of the element

Your code indicates that the `#wrapper` is to be 98% of the viewport but it should never be wider than 1080px. If 98% of the window width is greater than 1020px, the `#wrapper` will not get any wider!

Please comment if you don't understand :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It makes more sense now. If the browser window is 1400 pixels for example. Then the wrapper div element will only cover 1372px (98% of 1400) but since the max-width is set to 1020px, the wrapper div element will only go up to 1020px. Now the gap that forms will be 190px (1400 - 1020) /2 on both sides of the wrapper since I set the margin: 0 auto and this will center my wrapper div element?

Comment: @1290 It should, tell me what happens and comment with your results :)

Comment: @ww139 Not sure if I am doing this correctly but I checked the display of my macbook pro 13 inch and it says my scaled resolution looks like 1440x900. So I set the max-width property to be 1280px for the div element and the div element only takes up 1020px even though my display is 1440px wide. 

So I think the max-width is overriding the 98% width property which is scale the wrapper with respect to viewport.

Comment: @1290 You are doing it correctly. That is what your code was meant to do. The div has a MAXIMUM WIDTH of 1020px. If your browser window is (roughly) 1440px wide, your div has reached the maximum width. *your code is doing exactly what it is supposed to do* :)

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the help again!

Comment: @1290 That is what Stackoverflow was built for :)

Answer (score 1):

the width attribute is relative to your browser window's width, but by setting a maximum, this ensures that the width will not exceed 1020px (in this case) even if your browser window gets stretched to over 1020px